# Select all children and assign random background colors

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select child nodes and randomly change each divs background colour so I can quickly see how the page is broken up.
I found a nice little script to produce the hex but am struggling to apply that to selected divs .

This returns the hex values:

```
function random_color() {
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
}
return color;
};
```

And this is not looping through the children and assigning random values.

```
function loop(){
children = $("#container").children();
$(children).each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", random_color());
   }    
};

loop();
```

Just thought I would throw this one out there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I the future, paste your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ then click that JSHint button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$("#container").children().each(function() {      

     var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
     var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) 
       color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
        $(this).css("background-color", color);

});
```

or

```
$("#container").children().each(function() { 
        $(this).css("background-color", random_color());   
});
```

or

```
 children.each(function(){
 $(this).css("background-color", random_color());
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, always an education.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need `$` in `children` since it is already a jquery object

```
children.each(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", random_color());
 });
//^^---here    
};
```

**and noticed you missed a closing bracket `)` in each...**

Comment: It was that closing bracked indeed

Answer (score 1):

`children` already contains all the child elements..

So use:

```
function loop(){
children = $("#container").children();
children.each(function(){                  //<----  children instead of $(children)
   $(this).css("background-color", random_color());
 });    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` already returns a jquery object, so replace your following line:

```
$(children).each(function(){
```

for this one:

```
children.each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

First...you can just use children.each without the wrapping $(). Second...did you style your div's? I mean, do they have with's and height's?